# SQL Query. Converted records seen in a row

Tags: sql

If I have the following data layout seen below how could I return a query to switch the 'InforceInd' records displaying as '0' to '1'? (As long as 1 'policynumber' record contains a 'InforceInd' record of '1' switch all remaining rows from '0' to '1'?)

```
COLUMNS - PolicyNumber, InforceInd
ROW   -            XYZ, 1
ROW   -            XYZ, 0
ROW   -            XYZ, 0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, desired results is hlepful.

Comment: I don't get it. you just want to switch all 0s to 1 and not viceversa?

Comment: Yes. All the 0s to 1. This is for a table containing millions of rows. Every  transactions per policy creates a new row, but only the most recent row is updated with the inforceind as '1'. I need to be able to pull all the information for the policies as a whole where at least one row ='1'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET InforceInd = 1
WHERE
    InforceInd = 0
    AND
    PolicyNumber IN (
        SELECT PolicyNumber FROM MyTable WHERE InforceInd = 1);
```